# Python package to access Twitter via API without a "Twitter developer app"

Tags: python, api, twitter

I would like to access Twitter via API (to see followers, their followers etc), but without creating a "Twitter Developer API" (which got rejected).

Is there a python package which I can use to accomplish this (without registering a complicated and non-working "Twitter Developer API")?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [twitter-scraper](https://pypi.org/project/twitter-scraper/) in the past with reasonable success.

Comment: But it looks like I cannot obtain e.g. a list of followers of an user. Or a list of users someone follows.

Comment: @Alex I did not have a need for that functionality. You should be able to add it to the scraper, since it parses HTML from the Twitter website.

Answer (score 0):

The somewhat inelegant way would to use something like [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) and traverse the DOM tree for the information you want. This will work to access any data you need to so long as you can see it from a web browser.

It's somewhat time consuming to set up your functions and variables to however twitter organizes their webpage, but it will work. Another related and popular tool is [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/).

Obviously neither is ideal for accessing twitter information, but without any privileged API access, this is the most straightforward method available.